# FSCK doesn't run automatically

Tags: linux, debian, fstab, fsck

My `/etc/fstab` for my main OS parition:

```
UUID=5ee65c50-5672-42a6-9dcf-8bdba30c38aa  /   ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,data=writeback,errors=remount-ro    0   1
```

One of the options is set to mount the partition as readonly if there are any errors.

I want the OS to automatically run `fsck`, fix all the problems, and then reboot if any errors are found and the partition is set to readonly. I've also set `FSCKFIX=yes` on `/etc/defaults/rcS`. Currently, nothing works!

The only way I can get this to work is to run a bash function on `rc.local:`

```
TIMEOUT=30
check_disk() {
    DEV=/dev/mmcblk0p2

    local TPREV=$(date +%s);
    while :
    do
        ro=`awk '$4~/(^|,)ro($|,)/' /proc/mounts | grep "/dev/root"`
        if [ ! -z "${ro}" ]
        then
            echo -e "parition is readonly; running fsck now \n"
            fsck -y ${DEV}
            reboot
            break
        fi

        # Timeout
        local TNOW=$(date +%s)
        if ((TNOW - TPREV>=TIMEOUT)); then
            break
        fi

        sleep 1
    done
}

check_disk &
```

I need to loop for `x seconds` because `fstab` remounts the partition after `rc.local` runs.

I'm running Debian. Help is appreciated

Comment: This is very wrong. The vanilla setup for all Linux systems I have ever seen do the "if in doubt (unclean shutdown), run `fsck`; otherwise, run `fsck` each N boots or X weeks, whatever comes first" dance. With today's journalling filesystems you mostly don't notice the (fast) journal reply at all.

Comment: The weird thing is that `FSCKFIX=yes` doesn't work for you because it's exactly what you want. Look how the fsck command is built in `/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh`, maybe echo right before it's executed to see whether `-y` or `-a` is used. `cd /etc;grep -r 'FSCKFIX` should not show any assignments except in `/etc/defaults/rcS`.